# I'm having problems solving this indefinite integral

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{1}{x+1} \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^{2/3}dx$$

I have tried a $u$-substitution on the whole cube root thingy with $t$ but it did not work. I get $-3\int\frac{tdt}{(t^3-1)^2}$ and I don't know how to solve that.

Please help.

Comment: Assuming your substitution was performed correctly, this could make things simpler: $\frac{t}{(t^3-1)^2}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}(t^3-1))^2}=\frac{1}{(t^\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})^2}$

Comment: Can you show us how you arrived at the post-substitution integral?

Comment: It may be possible to solve this by rewriting $$(t^3-1)=(t-1)(t^2+t+1) =(t-1)\left(\left(t+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34\right)$$ and applying partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $t=\frac{x+1}{x}\iff \frac 1x=t-1$, then we get
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{x-(x+1)}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}=-(t-1)^2.$$
Hence, we have
$$\int\frac{1}{x+1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)^{2/3}dx=\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{t-1}+1}\cdot t^{2/3}\cdot \frac{-1}{(t-1)^2}dt=\int\frac{-t^{2/3}}{(t-1)+(t-1)^2}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{-t^{2/3}}{(t-1)t}dt=\int\frac{-t^{-(1/3)}}{t-1}dt.$$

Then, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20-%28%28t%5E%28%28-1%29/%283%29%29%29/%28t-1%29%29dt) gives you the answer.

So, the answer is 
$$\frac 12\ln (x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}+1)-\ln (1-x^{1/3})-\sqrt 3\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x^{1/3}+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)+C.$$

Comment: -1. The answer is incorrect as stated.